# Which machine learning models get affected by skewness of data?

Tags: machine-learning, skewness

I want to know which machine learning models get affected by skewness of the data. From what I think, `regression model` are the one which get affected while others like `tree based model`, `KNN`, `SVM`, `Neural Networks` won't get affected. But didn't found anything on google stating this.

Comment: Any ML model which predicts an average value for something will be affected by skewness. The more extreme the skewness, the more unreliable the prediction.

Comment: okay, thanks I got it!!!